# Liferay 6.2 social office chat portlet does not function properly

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

We recently moved from 6.1 to 6.2. What we've noticed and it is really strange, is that social office chat portlet had a normal behaviour at the beginning,

but suddenly, with no logged exception chat portlet displays zero online contacts and when trying to open it, it looks like trying to fetch contacts forever.

Is there a possibility that this has to do somehow with the maximum number of the online contacts. Because when I restarted jboss, online contacts can be displayed normally but after a while, when there were 5 online contacts available, the same problem occurred.

I also looked in database table and everything looks normal.
Any ideas about this? Has anyone noticed an incompatibility between 6.1 and 6.2 in social office chat portlet?